# Triggered Send Data Extensions deleted on a yearly basis

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, triggered-send

I work in my client's Salesforce instance, and we have an API set up that triggers transactional sends from our system to Salesforce. Last year, several of the data extensions tied to those triggers disappeared. This year it happened again, on the same date. And no one can figure out what happened. The API doesn't have permission to delete data extensions. My client insists they didn't delete them manually.

The fact that this happens yearly on the same day makes me think it's an automated process, not just someone deleting what they think is old data. I've been googling and I can't find any sort of data retention policy that might cause a data extension to be deleted entirely. Does anyone have any other ideas of what might have happened?

EDIT: I have considered contacting salesforce support, but would they even be able to see what happened if the Data Extension no longer exists?

Comment: There is a data retention policy that will remove all the data and the DE itself. That might be what the issue is.

Comment: there is an option to delete data and the de. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_manage_de_policies.htm&type=5  "All Records and Data Extension - When this option is selected, the entire data extension and the records inside the data extension are deleted."

Comment: Thanks to both of you for replying. Is this something that would be selected when the data extension is created? Or could it be set as an organization policy?